# Error creating new PHP project with Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse-pdt

I'm using Eclipse and I'm getting the following error after clicking `Finish` at the end of the `New PHP Project` creation wizard:

> Creation of element failed.
>
> org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.wizards.buildpath.BPListElement.appendEncodedSettings(Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;

Eclipse:
Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212

PDT:
PHP Development Tools (PDT)   7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Composer Support  7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) JUnit Tests   7.2.0.202005271851
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Mylyn Integration 7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) PHPUnit Support   7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Remote Project Synchronization Support    7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature   7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Source Code   7.0.0.201912041612
PHP Development Tools (PDT) Zend and Xdebug Profiler Support  7.0.0.201912041612

Reinstalling PDT and/or upgrading Eclipse are last resorts for me right now because I've heard of some users having trouble not being able to install PDT again after uninstalling, and every version update I've ever done of Eclipse has caused problems for me. I'd like to see if anyone understands the issue and if there are any other possible solutions I could try.

Comment: I have heard and see the opposite every day here on Stack Overflow: using outdated software is the number one reason for wasting time (your and our time). It is strange that you have different parts of PDT in different versions (PDT JUnit Tests is newer). You do not need to uninstall the old version to install the current version. Please note, retrocomputing is off-topic on Stack Overflow; there is a separate Stack Exchange for that.